# Iterate over a YAML complex map in helm

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am  using `Helm` v3 and trying to iterate over a complex object/map in a YAML definition file for Kubernetes network policy with the following content:
`values.yaml:`

```
networkPolicies:
  egress:
    - service: microservice-name
      destination:
        - podLabels:
            app=microservice-name
          namespaceLabels:
             company.com/microservices: microservice-name
      protocol: TCP
      ports:
        - 8444
```

At the k8s definition file, I have this code:
`egress-networkpolicy.yaml:`

```
{{- range $v, $rule := .Values.networkPolicies.egress  }}---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-kong-to-{{ $rule.service }}-egress
  namespace: kong
  annotations:
    description: Kong egress policies
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- range $label,$value := $rule.podSelector }}
      {{ $label }}: {{ $value }}
      {{- end }}
  egress:
    - to:
        {{- range $from := $rule.to }}
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              {{- range $label,$value := $from.podLabels }}
              {{ $label }}: {{ $value }}
              {{- end }}
          {{- if has $from "namespaceLabels" }}
          namespaceSelector:
            {{- if eq ( len $from.namespaceLabels ) 0 }} {}
            {{- else }}
            matchLabels:
              {{- range $label,$value := $from.namespaceLabels }}
              {{ $label }}: {{ $value }}
              {{- end }}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
      {{- if has $rule "ports" }}
      ports:
        {{- range $port := $rule.service.ports }}
        - protocol: {{ $port.protocol }}
        - port: {{ $port }}
        {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
    policyTypes:
      - Egress
{{ end -}}
```

Unfortunately when I run `helm template name-of-the-template` it throws the following error:

```
❯ helm template name-of-the-template --debug
install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: ""ate name-of-the-template --debug  

install.go:199: [debug] CHART PATH: /Users/user/charts/name-of-the-template


Error: template: name-of-the-template/templates/egress-networkpolicy.yaml:34:13: executing "name-of-the-template/templates/egress-networkpolicy.yaml" at <has $rule "ports">: error calling has: Cannot find has on type string
helm.go:88: [debug] template: name-of-the-template/templates/egress-networkpolicy.yaml:34:13: executing "name-of-the-template/templates/egress-networkpolicy.yaml" at <has $rule "ports">: error calling has: Cannot find has on type string
```

I can't find the reason for `Helm` throwing this error at that line, but not in similar code before that line.

Comment: Your encoding of `podLabels: "alpha=beta"` is introducing more work for yourself, since those need to be `alpha: beta` in the resulting yaml, and your `ports:` structure in that yaml template is entirely wrong, as it has multiple leading `-` characters. In short, this question is at risk of closure due to the large number of typos in it

Comment: So, you say the `{{- if has $rule "ports" }}` code is correct, but the `values.yaml` is the defective part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`has`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#has-musthas) template function checks for membership in a list.  In this context `$rule` is a mapping or dictionary (it is one of the items in the list under `egress`) and for that type you need to use [`hasKey`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#haskey) instead.

```yaml
{{- if hasKey $rule "ports" }}{{/* hasKey, not has */}}
ports:
  ...
{{- end }}
```

One thing that can simplify this slightly is to use the Go template `with` construct instead of `if` here.  `with` acts just like `if`, except it also rebinds the special variable `.` to the conditional value if it's truthy.  Accessing an undefined key in a map is okay but returns `nil`, which is falsey.  So in this context I might write

```yaml
{{- with $rule.ports }}
ports:
{{- range . }}
  - protocol: {{ $rule.protocol }}
    port: {{ . }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

(But note as I've written it that the `.` in the third and fifth lines are different variables, and that this usage also changes `.` as appears at the start of `.Values` or in `template "name" .`  In this little loop that's not going to be a practical problem.)

Comment: Thanks a lot David, switched from `if has` to `with` and it worked! Thx a lot!